# how do I find the maximum number of values of an array?

Tags: python, arrays

Say I have this array:

```
Letters = ["A","B","C","D"]
           #A           #B     #C   #D
numbers = [ [1,4,3],[2,4,5,5],[3],[2,3] ]
```

I would like to find which of these arrays is the longest and want an output like this:

```
B has the most values
```

I attempted something like this

```
Letters = ["A","B","C","D"]
               #A       #B     #C   #D
numbers = [ [1,4,3],[2,4,5,5],[3],[2,3] ]
length = 0
maximum = 0
for i in numbers:
    for x in i:
        lenght = len(numbers)
        if length > maximum:
            maximum = length
print(maximum)
```

Comment: actually C has the least amount of values

Comment: wait let me re edit the question

Comment: there done the format went wrong when I copied and pasted

Comment: great, what have you tried because this is similar to another question that you asked earlier so please provide your attempt

Comment: ok one second.....

Comment: This code won't work because there's a typo. Is this the actual code you're running?

Comment: @ForceBru no its an example to the real code

Comment: You're new here, so please read [ask] and take the [tour]. Point is, that your question makes several mistakes which could be avoided and also make your life easier.

Comment: ok il check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you only need the lists' lengths and their positions, convert `numbers` to a list of lengths, where the positions of each length correspond to the positions of each sublist:

   ```
   numbers_lengths = list(map(len, numbers)) # using `list` is not necessary
   # numbers_lengths == [3, 4, 1, 2]
   ```
2. You want to associate each element of `letters` with a length, which means you need a different data structure:

   ```
   Map = dict(zip(letters, numbers_lengths))
   # Map == {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 1, 'D': 2}
   ```
3. Just find the key whose value is the greatest:

   ```
   result = max([(length, letter) for letter, length in Map.items()])
   # result == (4, 'B')
   ```

   This works because you can compare tuples: `((2, 'a') > (0, 'b')) is True`.

   3.1 Another approach:

   ```
   result = max(Map.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1])
   # result == ('B', 4)
   ```
4. So, the answer is `result[1] == 'B'`

Answer (score 1):

You could `zip` both lists and use the `max` built-in function with a custom `key` to find the tuple with the longest list:

```
from operator import itemgetter
s = max(zip(Letters, numbers), key= lambda x: len(itemgetter(1)(x)))[0]
```

**Output**

```
print(s, 'has the most values')
# B has the most values
```